# Minecraft Bedrock Chunks not loading

Tags: technical-issues, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have Minecraft Bedrock V1.16.100. When I travel fast (like on a horse or on an elytra) the chunks in front of me don't load and I see everything as transparent. My specs:-

```
intel i3 5005U
intel hd graphics 5500
4GB ram
```

I used to think that these system resources are too low to run Minecraft and so the chunks do not load. But recently I saw my friend who does not face this problem even though his system specs are much low as compared to my. His specs :-

```
intel pentium 2nd gen dual core
128mb dedicated graphics 512mb total(or something like that. I don't remember exactly)
4GB ram
```

We both are running Windows 10 v 1909.

I don't use any Shaders or mods. Also I have set Minecraft to lowest settings.

[image: Here is a picture for reference]

Comment: First of all, I would recommend updating. That will like 90% fix it

Answer (score -1):

This is a common problem. Restart, your device, restart Minecraft, and then open it up. It should be fixed.

Answer (score -1):

This most likely might be the hardware because the Intel Pentium 2nd Gen dual-core processor is less powerful than the Intel Core i3 which is the minimum processor for the system requirements. But you could try optimizing your computer to run it a better. Make sure Minecraft and your system is up to date. Make sure your graphics driver is up to date. Try to minimize background processes which you can see them in the task manager. Make sure there is no corrupted system files which can slow down your computer, you can do that by running command prompt as administrator and running the command `sfc /scannow` which will check for corrupted system files and restore it. Hope this helps.